# Any way to turn a macOS Notification into a FULL SCREEN notification

Tags: macos, notifications

Is there a way to turn a regular macOS Notification into a FULL SCREEN notification (ie: one that displays the message across the entire screen)?

Comment: Are you trying to to ensure that a particular notification is not missed by the user? Or something else? There may be other ways of doing that.

Comment: Yes, trying to ensure that a notification is not missed by user.

Comment: Specifically, I use Session (an excellent pomodoro focus timer) when I'm writing. That app sends a notification to the macOS Notification Center and it displays a small window in the upper right. 
I would like to have this notification to appear full screen to FORCE me to stop writing.

Comment: Grateful if someone can answer this question. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want notifications to appear as alerts?

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to get Pomodoro stop/break notifications in full screen, [Flow app](https://flowapp.info/) has that function in its free version. The app is also available in a Pro version with a few more features.

I haven't found a workaround allowing notifs various apps to do the same yet, though.